# Business One: cannot seem to display the totals in a matrix

Tags: sapb1

I have implemented a custom form with a matrix in an addon for *SAP Business One* v. 10.00.150, but cannot cause it to display totals under some of the matrix columns. I have:

```cs
static Column AddCol( Cols cols, string id, string title, BoFieldsType type, BoFormItemTypes itype, bool editable )
{   Column mcol;
    // cols.Mx is the SAPbouiCOM.Columns
    mcol = cols.Mx.Add( id, itype );
    mcol.TitleObject.Caption = title;
    cols.Dt.Add( id, type, 254 );
    mcol.DataBind.Bind( DtId, id );
    mcol.Editable = editable;
    if( type == ft_Quantity )
    {   mcol.ColumnSetting.SumType = BoColumnSumType.bst_Auto;  }
    return mcol;
}
```

The totals row is created in the matrix, but all the values are empty regardless of the matrix contents. What is missing? The matrix is bound to a `DataTable` datasource and works...

### Update

I have localised the error—auto totals work only for the last column in the matrix, at least for me. Please, try the following code with `true` and `false` in the condition. If column `2` is added, the totals in column `1` miraculously stop working:

```cs
// dt is SAPbouiCOM.DataTable
// mx is SAPbouiCOM.Matrix
Column   col;
dt.Columns.Add( "1", BoFieldsType.ft_Quantity, 0 );
col = mx.Columns.Add( "1", BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT );
col.TitleObject.Caption = "Should have a total";
col.DataBind.Bind( dt.UniqueID, "1" );
col.ColumnSetting.SumType = BoColumnSumType.bst_Auto;

// If another column follows a column with auto totals, the auto totals
// are not displayed -- try below with false and true:
if( true )
{   dt.Columns.Add( "2", BoFieldsType.ft_AlphaNumeric, 254 );
    col = mx.Columns.Add( "2", BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT );
    col.TitleObject.Caption = "Breaks auto totals.";
    col.DataBind.Bind( dt.UniqueID, "2" );
}

dt.Rows.Add(2);
dt.SetValue( "1", 0, 1.00 );
dt.SetValue( "1", 1, 0.23 );
mx.LoadFromDataSource();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A workaround

Thanks to Praxiom's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77021646/2862241), I have found that the bug does not occur if the `DataTable` is sturctured via `.ExecuteQuery`. This let me implement the following workaround:

```cs
static void HackStructDt( DataTable dt )
{   const string QTempl = "SELECT TOP 0 {0} FROM RDR1";

    int      i, n;
    ColEntry ce  ;
    string   fields, field, fldspec;
    string   query;

    n = ColTab.Count; // my metadata with column specs.

    fields = "";
    for( i = 0; i < n; i += 1 )
    {   ce = ColTab[ i ];
        field = "";
        switch( ce.Type )
        {   case ft_AlphaNumeric:
            case ft_Text        : field = "Address"  ; break;
            case ft_Integer     : field = "DocEntry" ; break;
            case ft_ShortNumber : field = "GrossBase"; break;
            case ft_Measure     : field = "Weight1"  ; break;
            case ft_Percent     : field = "VatPrcnt" ; break;
            case ft_Price       : field = "Price"    ; break;
            case ft_Quantity    : field = "Quantity" ; break;
            case ft_Rate        : field = "Rate"     ; break;
            case ft_Sum         : field = "VatSum"   ; break;
            case ft_Date        : field = "ShipDate" ; break;
            case ft_Float       : throw new Exception("Float type is not supported");
        }
        fldspec = field + " AS " + ce.Id;
        if( fields != "" ) fields = fields + ", ";
        fields = fields + fldspec;
    }
    query = Format( QTempl, fields );
    dt.ExecuteQuery( query );
}
```

Comment: Marking the workaround as a solution *until the real thing comes along*.

Answer (score 0):

In it's most simplest form a column can be added, bound, populated and summed as follows:

```
dtTest = this.UIAPIRawForm.DataSources.DataTables.Item("dtTest");
dtTest.ExecuteQuery("Select top 50 Quantity 'TestColumn' From RDR1");
mtx.Columns.Add("xx", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
mtx.Columns.Item("xx").DataBind.Bind(dtTest.UniqueID, "TestColumn");
mtx.Columns.Item("xx").ColumnSetting.SumType = SAPbouiCOM.BoColumnSumType.bst_Auto;
mtx.LoadFromDataSource();
```

Adding the column in this way will reliably include the totals.

Comment: Your code works indeed, but once I add a second column after the one with auto totals, the totals are gone again. I have edited my question with actual test code. Can you please try it on your side?

Comment: Your example executes a query, whereas mine constructs the `DataTable` in code. This is when it breaks. [This](https://pastebin.com/raw/pzkFknee) is your example modified to reproduce the probelm. Please, test it.

Comment: thanks Anton, im away from my dev machine but will test monday. hopefully we can get to the bottom of this. as an aside, are you fully set on using a matrix? i really only use them when dealing with a a UDO and find grids much easier to work with, especially as you can spit the data to XML and then use LINQ! 

Comment: Thank you very much, *Praxion*. Yes, I prefer matrices, and I have a super-fact class for populating and reading `DataTable` datasources via *XML*.

Comment: No good news for me?

Comment: Your answer not solving my problem, I cannot vote for it or mark it as a solution, but I thank you for the idea of a workaround, viz. structuring the `DataTable` via a query instead of adding columns manually.

Comment: Totally understandable, I haven't had any luck luck constructing the table without the .ExecuteQuery either, I wonder if it a bug within the SDK. Yours is an elegant solution and worthy of an upvote!  I shall leave this answer here to serve as a simple workaround also.

Comment: Thank you for the help, @Praxiom. May I ask you to please file an incident to *B1* support? Unfortunately I cannot do it from Russia...